# Can't run a tag recursively while generating xml in SQL language

Tags: sql-server, xml, casting

I want the attribute tag in my sql query to run recursively. My query is below.

```
SELECT
CAST(415 as int) as 'version',
CAST(1942605 as int) as 'form_id',
CAST(1145 as int) as 'customer_id',

CAST('emailgeneric' as varchar(20)) AS [subscriber/attribute/attr_name],
CAST(U.Email as varchar(100)) AS [subscriber/attribute/attr_value],

CAST('pnmgiven' as varchar(20)) AS [subscriber/attribute/attr_name],
CAST(U.Name as varchar(50)) AS [subscriber/attribute/attr_value],

FROM [example.com].[dbo].[KMU_Users] AS U
LEFT JOIN [example.com].[dbo].[Address] AS A ON U.UserID=A.UserID
LEFT JOIN [example.com].[dbo].[Provinces] AS P ON P.Code=A.City

WHERE Email='example@hotmail.com'
FOR XML PATH('subscription_data')
```

The XML output of my query is available below.

```
<subscription_data>
  <version>415</version>
  <form_id>1942605</form_id>
  <customer_id>1145</customer_id>
  <subscriber>
    <attribute>
      <attr_name>emailgeneric</attr_name>
      <attr_value>example@hotmail.com</attr_value>
      <attr_name>pnmgiven</attr_name>
      <attr_value>John</attr_value>
    </attribute>
  </subscriber>
</subscription_data>
```

I want the attribute tag to be repeatedly opened and closed on each attribute. For example, below is the structure I want. How can I run the tag repeatedly?

```
<subscription_data>
  <version>415</version>
  <form_id>1942605</form_id>
  <customer_id>1145</customer_id>
  <subscriber>
    <attribute>
      <attr_name>emailgeneric</attr_name>
      <attr_value>example@hotmail.com</attr_value>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
      <attr_name>pnmgiven</attr_name>
      <attr_value>John</attr_value>
    </attribute>
  </subscriber>
</subscription_data>
```

Comment: add an empty subscriber between pairs of attrib_name&value: `CAST(U.Email as varchar(100)) AS [subscriber/attribute/attr_value], '' AS [subscriber], CAST('pnmgiven' as varchar(20)…`

Answer (score 2):

One method would be to nest the nodes for `subscriber` and then break up the `attribute` with a blank value:

```sql
SELECT 415 AS version, --This is a literal, it doesn't need casting. Don't use literal string aliases.
       1942605 AS form_id,  --This is a literal, it doesn't need casting. Don't use literal string aliases.
       1145 AS customer_id,  --This is a literal, it doesn't need casting. Don't use literal string aliases.
       (SELECT 'emailgeneric' AS [attribute/attr_name], --This is a literal, it doesn't need casting.
               CAST(U.Email AS varchar(100)) AS [attribute/attr_value],'',
               'pnmgiven' AS [attribute/attr_name], --This is a literal, it doesn't need casting.
               CAST(U.Name AS varchar(50)) AS [attribute/attr_value]
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE) AS subscriber
FROM (VALUES('example@hotmail.com','John'))U(Email,name)
WHERE Email = 'example@hotmail.com'
FOR XML PATH('subscription_data');
```

So for your query it would look like this:

```sql
USE [example.com]; --As it's all against the same database, connect to the right one
                   --Then you don't need 3 part naming
GO
SELECT 415 AS version, 
       1942605 AS form_id, 
       1145 AS customer_id,
       (SELECT 'emailgeneric' AS [attribute/attr_name],
               CAST(U.Email AS varchar(100)) AS [attribute/attr_value],'',
               'pnmgiven' AS [attribute/attr_name], 
               CAST(U.Name AS varchar(50)) AS [attribute/attr_value]
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE) AS subscriber
FROM [dbo].[KMU_Users] AS U
--The other JOINs are LEFT JOINs and the tables aren't referenced,
--So seems that they aren't needed.
WHERE Email = 'example@hotmail.com'
FOR XML PATH('subscription_data');
```

Comment: @EymenBatınYacı if this solved your issue you should consider marking this as the answer. It lets others know your issue is solved and it provides a little bit of reputation to the poster as a reward.